# PDFBox 2.0.3 - Image Coordinates returned from PrintImageLocations.java not as expected

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am attempting to extract the **x**, **y**, **width** and **height** of images embedded into a PDF using the *PrintImageLocations.java* as per the below location:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/2.0.3/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java

However, all instances of the returned values do not align with what i am expecting. As the values are so far out of whack, i ran the **SaveImagesInPdf** class from the below location to make sure PDFBox was looking at the right image, and it did indeed locate and extract the desired image perfectly.

https://www.tutorialkart.com/pdfbox/extract-images-from-pdf-using-pdfbox/

What i am expecting is the same **x**, **y**, **width** and **height** that i'd input as a *Rectangle2D* to the *PDFTextStripperByArea* class when extracting specific text.

I've done a fair amount of internet research, i can't really find a straight answer. From what i have read, i think the coordinates system i am using to extract text is not the same as what it is for images.

If that is a case, is there anyway to translate the values that *PrintImageLocations.java* brings back to the *Rectangle2D* coordinates i use for  *PDFTextStripperByArea* ?

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The current version is 2.0.8. Could you please link to a PDF?

Comment: I'm using PDFBox for a client and the latest version they have available is 2.0.3, so i am unable to obtain 2.0.8 at this time.

Likewise, the PDF in question is a client PDF so i am unable to share this. However i found a PDF online for an example, but when i ran PrintImageLocations, it did indeed return the desired results.

I can only assume it's something to do with the client PDF as it goes through a number of systems before PDF generation occurs. As such, this isn't a problem with PDFBox.

Comment: Who knows... it's always possible that there's a problem in PDFBox, but without the PDF it's not possible. The best would be to ask the client. Or have a look at PDFDebugger to the PDF file, altough you'll need a good understanding of the PDF specification...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The Y-positions of my images were way off (top of the page and not the bottom of the page). After a ton of searching, I finally found a new PrintImageLocations had the following code, which does the necessary adjustments to correct whatever was the issue:

```
    PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;
    int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight();

    Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
    float imageXScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
    float imageYScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();

    float yScaling = ctmNew.getScaleY();
    float angle = (float)Math.acos(ctmNew.getValue(0, 0)/ctmNew.getScaleX());
    if (ctmNew.getValue(0, 1) < 0 && ctmNew.getValue(1, 0) > 0)
    {
        angle = (-1)*angle;
    }

    PDPage page = getCurrentPage();
    double pageHeight = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
    ctmNew.setValue(2, 1, (float)(pageHeight - ctmNew.getTranslateY() - Math.cos(angle)*yScaling));
    ctmNew.setValue(2, 0, (float)(ctmNew.getTranslateX() - Math.sin(angle)*yScaling));

    // because of the moved 0,0-reference, we have to shear in the opposite direction
    ctmNew.setValue(0, 1, (-1)*ctmNew.getValue(0, 1));
    ctmNew.setValue(1, 0, (-1)*ctmNew.getValue(1, 0));

    System.out.println("NEW NEW:  position in PDF = " + ctmNew.getTranslateX() + ", " + ctmNew.getTranslateY() + " in user space units");
```

Comment: The positions weren't *way off*, they were merely given in a  coordinate system different from the one you expected and using a different anchor point than you expected. Thus, the *issue* merely were wrong expectations.